# How do i deploy my google assistant bot so that everyone can use it?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Till now i have only used dialogflow to design simple conversation and tested the bot on Actions on google.

Answer (score 0):

The AoG documentation [Publish Your Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing) describes what you need to do to have your Action published. You can also check out the [Publish Checklist](https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/) for the best experience. After your Action has been approved, it will be available to the users. Best of luck!